# In Clojure, what happens when you call sql/with-connection within another sql/with-connection?

Tags: clojure, database-connection

```
(sql/with-connection *db-atom* (insert-data value1 value2)
 (sql/with-connection *db-atom* (read-tuple-as-map)))
```

From the above example, does the nested `sql/with-connection` open a new connection to the DB? Or does it use the one that was created earlier?

Comment: there are a couple of libraries that have used the short name sql, could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was referring to: clojure.contrib.sql/with-connection

Comment: from that can I assume that you are using Clojure 1.2.0?

Comment: Clojure 1.4 really is a lot better. Upgradeing to 1.2 fixes many bugs and I have never seen it require code changes. #OMGUpgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I would in general recommend using  clojure.java.jdbc instead of clojure.contrib.sql because the latter is not supposed to work with clojure newer than 1.2.0.

in clojure.java.jdbc `with-connection` uses binding to add the connection to a map of connections in the *db* var for any wrapped calls, so the second one will overwrite the frist one.

from: [jdbc.clj](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/jdbc.clj#L297)

```
(defn with-connection*
  "Evaluates func in the context of a new connection to a database then
  closes the connection."
  [db-spec func]
  (with-open [^java.sql.Connection con (get-connection db-spec)]
    (binding [*db* (assoc *db* :connection con :level 0 :rollback (atom false))]
      (func))))
```

Comment: for clojure.contrib.sql it will also replace the first binding with the second.